# How do I make this program work with spaces? (Text to ASCII and ASCII to text)

Tags: python

I wrote a program that turns a text into ASCII numbers, and then it turns the ASCII numbers back into the original text. Right now it works with both lowercase letters and uppercase letters but it doesn't work with spaces. This is how my code looks right now:

```
message_hidden = input("Enter a message that will be hidden: ")
hidden = ""
norm_message = ""
for i in message_hidden:
    hidden = hidden + str(ord(i)-23)
print(hidden)

for i in range(0, len(hidden), 2):
    code = hidden[i] + hidden[i+1]
    norm_message = norm_message + (chr(int(code)+23))
print("The first message was: ", norm_message)
```

My first attempt was to rewrite the first loop like this:

```
for i in message_hidden:
    if i.isalpha():
        hidden = hidden + str(ord(i)-23)
    else:
        hidden = hidden + i
print(hidden)
```

And from here I don't know how I should write the second loop to make it work. Can anyone give me some suggestions about how I should go from here?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the exact problem with your code? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: "Right now it works with both lowercase letters and uppercase letters but it doesn't work with spaces." I want the program to be able to handle strings with spaces. Like if I type in "Good Morning" it will not work, but it will work with "GoodMorning" and "goodmorning" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord(' ') == 32` and `32-23 == 9`, which is single digit. You are assuming that your numerical codes are all 2 digits. If you want to keep that assumption, you need to find a different way to encrypt the space character. To do this find a 2-digit number that *isn't* one of the numbers obtained by `a-zA-Z`. Using an explicit `if` -- encrypt the space character to this number. When decrypting, you will also need to use an explicit `if` to handle this case.

Alternatively, find a different function (other that subtracting by 23), which you apply to `ord(letter)` -- one which gives 2 digit numbers for all `ord()` values that you are interested in. There are infinitely many functions which satisfy this property. Whether or not you can find one which would require less code than simply putting a band aid on the space character is another question.